# how to find complex roots in trigonometric equation

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, complex-numbers, maple

Hi I would like to find complex roots of the following equation

x.(1+cos(x.L).cosh(x.L))-i.d.(cos(x.L).sinh(x.L)-sin(x.L).cosh(x.L)) =0

where x=x1+i.x2, x1 and x2 are real numbers. By using Maple (in the following code), I found some roots in the form x1+i.x2, -x1-i.x2, -x1+i.x2, x1-i.x2

```
restart:
L:=10:

CodeTools:-Usage( RootFinding[Analytic]((z)*(1+cos(L*z)*cosh(L*z))-I*(d)*(cos(L*z)*sinh(L*z)-sin(L*z)*cosh(L*z)), re=-10*Pi..10*Pi, im=-10*Pi..10*Pi) ):
A:=[%]:
S := sort(A):

n := 1000; for i to n do S[i] end do;
```

and I would like to compare my results, which I got by Maple, with Python. I am a beginner for Python. My question is how I can improve my code to find whole complex roots from the nonlinear equation. Here so far my code is below :

```
import numpy as np
import cmath
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


d = 1
L = 10

def f(x):
return np.abs( x * (1 + cmath.cos(L*x) * cmath.acosh(L*x)) 
     -1j*d * (cmath.cos(L*x) * cmath.asinh(L*x)- cmath.sin(L*x) *cmath.acosh(L*x))
             )

x = fsolve(f, 0.01)
print x, f(x)
```

Comment: so what is the problem with your code? Notice that you forgot to actually ask a question!

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39027107/edit) your question and add a clear, precise question (not "what can I do?")! I think your question might be very interesting, but as it is, we don't know what that question might be. Also, your Python code isn't correctly indented, please correct that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for comment! I tried to make more clear my question.

Comment: although a step in the right direction, what does "I could not find whole roots" imply? Does that mean there *should* be roots, but fsolve can't find them? as far as I can see, f(x) has no real roots, how are you checking root with imaginary parts?